# $\otimes$ (tensor symbol use) in infix conversion

Tags: tensors

Reformulated problem.

I am using the code:

```
HasseGraph[g_] := 
 With[{vlist = VertexList[g]}, 
Graph[g, VertexLabels -> 

Thread[
 vlist -> Map[# /. {A -> TensorProduct, 
      B -> (Infix[Pa[##], Pa] &)} &, vlist]]]]

 HasseGraph[Graph[{A[1, 2] -> A[2, B[3, 4]]}]]
```

When executed, the vertex labels of the graph have the tensor product evaluated and also removed at one point. The result for A[2, B[3, 4]
is 2(3 Pa 4)

Instead I want the tensor product displayed (everywhere where A is replaced by `TensorProduct`) by the actual symbol for the tensor product *and* the result needs to be displayed in infix notation.

Can it be achieved using `Hold` in the above code?

Comment: `\[CircleTimes]` isn't used with `~`. It's already an `Infix` symbol. Maybe you're thinking of `Infix[(a~CircleTimes~b), CircleTimes]`?

Comment: Since you mentioned tensor, are you looking for `\[TensorProduct]`?

Comment: Either way, errors occur. But I am looking for CircleTimes info.

Comment: @Mike just do `a~CircleTimes~b` or `a \[CircleTimes] b`... It'll do what you want. `\[CircleTimes]` is a special unicode character that's designed to be an `Infix` version of `CircleTimes`

Comment: I updated my question to illustrate the problem. Using \[CircleTimes] instead of the Infix operation produces an error.

Comment: @b3m2a1 I updated the problem statement.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured out that this need HoldForm (not Hold) and that the following works

```
Map[# /. {A -> (HoldForm[TensorProduct[##]] &), 
B -> (Infix[Pa[##], Pa] &)} &, {A[A[1, 2], 3]}]
```